# Why do my bytes appear corrupted when I try to encode a value of 127? (Yes, 127, not "over 127")

Tags: scala, encoding, byte, arrays

I'm using `scala.reflect.internal.pickling.ByteCodecs` to encode a `Array[Byte]`. Info about the encoding scheme can be found [here](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~dubochet/new_pickle.pdf).

As soon as the array contains a value of `127`, then I see `-64,-128, 1` in the encoded bytes when I expect to see a `0`[(gist)](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/6559898), and I can no longer parse the encoded bytes.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.internal.pickling._
import scala.reflect.internal.pickling._

scala> import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.Arrays

scala> val byte = Array[Byte](127)
byte: Array[Byte] = Array(127)

scala> val byteEncoded = ByteCodecs.encode(byte)
byteEncoded: Array[Byte] = Array(-64, -128, 1)

scala> val byteDecoded = Arrays.copyOf(byteEncoded, ByteCodecs.decode(byteEncoded))
byteDecoded: Array[Byte] = Array(127, 0) //this line is as expected
```

What's going on here?

How can I get a correctly encoded array if the original `Array[Byte]` contains a `127`?

Thanks very much for taking a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any of the details—if your chain encode->decode reproduces the input (which you say it does), then it works correctly IMO. does the spec say anything about *how* byte arrays are encoded? Because if not, it is free to do what it pleases...

Looking at the source (Scala 2.10.0)

```
def encode(xs: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = avoidZero(encode8to7(xs))
```

This does some severe re-encoding, so I wouldn't expect to find your input array in a human readable form in the encoded array.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. You were right about the '127' not being the culprit that prevented parsing, as I was able to go there-and-back in other contexts besides above. I can only guess what the real issue was, but I solved it by replacing `encode` with `encode8to7` plus further processing _a la_ [Scala AnnotationInfos](http://bit.ly/19LhuUe).